# How do I run 1-855 data points( imported from excel sheet) into a formula to obtain value for each data point?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, import

I am very new to *Mathematica* and I just couldn't figure out the solution for the following problem.

I have two columns in an Excel file. I have imported the 1st column as `temp` (1- 855 data points), and the 2nd as `den` (1-855 data points). I am trying to calculate the ellipticity (`ellip`, last formula) for each value of `temp` and `den` However, my script only returns one value. I need the `ellip` values for each of my `temp`and `den` concentrations.

My question is how do I run 1-855 data points of `temp` and `den` into the `ellip` formula so that it will return values for each data point?

Below is my *Mathematica* script.

```
a = -29846.66713137483;

b = 49.10083342826049;

c = -5927.651357897106;

d = 9402.228131251579;

e = -36.722337085166785;

f = 0.029490823878660512;

g = -528.5106658275561;

dCp = 19.731822683160715;

dH = 0.2566239190680801;

m = 0.995288747060038;

Tm = 372.92653842275854;

temp= Import["/Users/Justin Yeoh/Documents/Professor \ Szyperski/Research/CD/CombinedMelt_copy.xlsx", {"Data", 1, Range[1, 855], {1}}];

den = Import["/Users/Justin Yeoh/Documents/Professor \ Szyperski/Research/CD/CombinedMelt_copy.xlsx", {"Data", 1,Range[1, 855], {2}}];

thetaF[a_, b_, c_, temp_, den_] := a + b*temp + c*den;

thetaU[d_, e_, f_, g_, temp_, den_] := d + e*temp + f*temp^2 + g*den;

dG[dH_, dCP_, m_, Tm_, temp_, den_] := 
  dH*(1 - temp/Tm) - dCP*((Tm - temp) + temp*Log[temp/Tm]) + (-m)*den;

ellip[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, dH_, dCP_, m_, Tm_, temp_,den_] := 
  (thetaF[a, b, c, temp, den] + 
   thetaU[d, e, f, g, temp, den] Exp[-dG[dH, dCP, m, Tm, temp, den]/(.00198 temp)])/
     (1 + Exp[-dG[dH, dCP, m, Tm, temp, den]/(.00198*temp)])
```

Comment: What is the format of the data in your `temp` and `den` variables?

Comment: Could you try escaping your file name/paths? i.e. ["C:\\Users\\peter\\data.xslx"]

Comment: Hi David, what is format of data? I am sorry I only know that  both variables are in xlsx.

Comment: When you import your data, look at it carefully. For example,  `FullForm[temp]` will show you exactly what you have imported.

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried to escape the file name /paths. Unfortunately, I still get just one value for my ellip.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for the info. I have checked and it seems all my data has been imported.

Comment: I don't know if the program is actually adding all my ellip values instead of returning the ellip value for each of my data point (855 data). Is there a way to run each of these data into my ellip function ? so that in the end i will a value of each

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 5):

In cases like yours, I am a great believer in simplifying the code by using [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to insert the parameters into the function definitions rather than carrying a mess of them around in arguments. Here is how this idea applies to your code.

```
With[{
  a = -29846.66713137483,
  b = 49.10083342826049,
  c = -5927.651357897106,
  d = 9402.228131251579,
  e = -36.722337085166785,
  f = 0.029490823878660512,
  g = -528.5106658275561,
  dCP = 19.731822683160715,
  dH = 0.2566239190680801,
  m = 0.995288747060038,
  Tm = 372.92653842275854
  },
  thetaF[temp_, den_] := a + b temp + c den;
  thetaU[temp_, den_] := d + e temp + f temp^2 + g den;
  dG[temp_, den_] := 
    dH (1 - temp/Tm) - dCP ((Tm - temp) + temp Log[temp/Tm]) + (-m) den;
  ellip[temp_, den_] :=
    With[{u = Exp[-dG[temp, den]/(.00198 temp)]}, 
      (thetaF[temp, den] + u thetaU[temp, den])/(1 + u)]]
```

The advantage of making the definitions this way is that they are clearer to the reader of the code and the code actually performs somewhat better.

With the above you can get your values, presuming that `temp` and `den` are lists of real numbers, with

```
Thread[ellip[temp, den]]
```

#### Update

The above is fine if the parameters are truly constants, but you might do another set of experiments with a different set of parameters. Let's look into handling this more general problem.

I will start by defining a function that builds the `ellis` function from when given the parameters.

```
ellipticity[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, dCP_, dH_, m_, Tm_] := 
  (
    Clear[thetaF, thetaU, dG, ellip];
    thetaF[temp_, den_] := a + b temp + c den;
    thetaU[temp_, den_] := d + e temp + f temp^2 + g den;
    dG[temp_, den_] := 
      dH (1 - temp/Tm) - dCP ((Tm - temp) + temp Log[temp/Tm]) + (-m) den;
    ellip[temp_, den_] := 
      With[{u = Exp[-dG[temp, den]/(.00198 temp)]}, 
       (thetaF[temp, den] + u thetaU[temp, den])/(1 + u)];
    ellip
  )
```

Note that `ellipticity` builds a new set of functions returns a the `ellip` function every time it is called. Returning `ellip` is a matter of convenience.

Now `ellipticity` can be used in the same way a `ellis` was above, but the parameters are given to it as arguments.

The follow demonstrates usage. I have fabricated a small test data set, but not knowing what are reasonable ranges for the `temp` and `den`, the results are not to be taken seriously.

```
Module[{n = 6, temp, den},
  SeedRandom[1];
  {temp, den} = {RandomReal[{50., 99.}, n], RandomReal[1., n]};
  With[{
    a = -29846.66713137483, b = 49.10083342826049, 
    c = -5927.651357897106, d = 9402.228131251579, 
    e = -36.722337085166785, f = 0.029490823878660512, 
    g = -528.5106658275561, dCP = 19.731822683160715, 
    dH = 0.2566239190680801, m = 0.995288747060038, 
    Tm = 372.92653842275854
    },
    Thread[ellipticity[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, dCP, dH, m, Tm][temp, den]]]]
```

> {6047.8742264, 7334.1625993, 6168.1045631, 6961.3344009, 7132.5852188, 7135.6808087}

Whether or not you would want to have a master function such as `ellipticity` is a matter of coding style and coding taste. But such functions can be useful and *Mathematica* has no problem dealing with a function call where the head is in itself a function call. *Mathematica* evaluates an expression's head before it evaluates the expression's arguments. In fact, the head expression of a function call may reasonably be regarded as argument zero the call.

Answer (score 3):

If `temp` and `den` have all 855 data points then you can use `Thread` since all other parameters are scalars the dimensions of `temp` and `den` are equal.

```
Thread@ellip[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, dH, dCP, m, Tm, temp, den]
```

If you are having issues with the Excel filename then try `SystemDialogInput`.

```
{temp, den} = Transpose@
  Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"], 
    {"XLSX", "Data", 1, Range[855], {1, 2}}]
```

Hope this helps.